# Regex Visa + Mastercard with Spaces need Add Amex

Tags: regex, forms, validation

I have this Regex to validate Visa and Master card with spaces, it works perfect.

```
^(?:4\d{3}|5[1-5]\d{2}|6011|3[47]\d{2})([- ]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}$
```

**Visa**

4111111111111111 = true

4111 1111 1111 1111 = true

**Master**

5500000000000004 = true

5500 0000 0000 0004 = true

**American Express**

340000000000009 = false

3400 0000 0000 009 = false

I need **add Amex to the regex**, I need the last two true, can anyone help me please?
Thank you!

Comment: Could it be that you have a typo in the first Visa number? I tried it and it was matched too. See: https://regex101.com/r/WhUwLC/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(assuming `4111111111111111 = false` is a typo)*

You can use the following *regex* :

```
^(?:4\d{3}|5[1-5]\d{2}|6011|3[47]\d{2})([-\s]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{3,4}$
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vtt9bi/3)

Comment: But you can not add `3\d{3}|` in the first group. As ysanmiguel added already the correct case for Amex cards which is `3[47]\d{2}`.

Comment: ahh.. my bad.. thnx for the catch :)

Comment: 4111111111111111 was true, sorry my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the background how you use this regex but i would do this in two steps:

**Step 1:**
Remove all spaces with one line of code. Since spacing should not define whether a number is valid/invalid.

**Step 2:** 
Use this regex

```
^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13})$
```

This catches a few more rules on MasterCards.

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) (Shortend expression since fewer types of cards are needed)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhUwLC/2)